# Wrong output of mahout PFPGrowth algorithm?

Tags: apache, hadoop, data-mining, mahout

I'm using latest trunk version of mahout's PFP Growth implementation on top of a hadoop cluster to determine frequent patterns in movielens dataset.
In a previous step I converted the dataset to a list of transactions as the pfp growth algorithm needs that input format.

However, the output I get is unexpected

For example for item 1017 the only frequent pattern is

> 1017    ([100,1017, 50])

I would also expect a pattern like ([1017], X) with X >= 50 in that line.

I also testset an example input

> 1,2,3
>
> 1,2,3
>
> 1,3

and the output I get is

> 1  ([1, 3],3), ([1],3), ([1, 3, 2],2)
>
> 2  ([1, 3, 2],2)
>
> 3  ([1, 3],3), ([1, 3, 2],2)

There are missing patterns like ([1,2],2)

What is wrong?

Comment: I'd assume that PFPGrowth is only probabilistically complete? Many distributed "big data" algorithms are only approximative.

Comment: Is it getting pruned by minSupport?

Comment: Probabilistic would be very bad. The minSupport cannot be the reason as you can see there are patterns included with a support of 2. Did you implemente the Algorithm Sean? I need to use it for my Bachelor thesis. Im trying to extend the pfp growth. As additinal step i first convert the movielens dataset to a list of transactions, then run the pfp growth steps and then do another map/reduce step to extract all associations rules including values for support and confidence.

Comment: (P)FP Gwroth is definately not probabilistic. So i expect a correct and complete output same as an apriori algorithm would do.

Comment: the non-parallel FP Growth that is used by PFP seems to cause the problem. I have to look at this a little closer.

Comment: I have heard from colleagues who have tested the FPGrowth implementation in Mahout, that it has some bugs. I did not try it by myself. You may check carefully the documentation and contact the authors if you are not sure how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the FP Algorithm does not output subsets of a frequent pattern if its support is not greater. It's described here:
http://www.searchworkings.org/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/396093

I need to rewrite the code for my use.

Answer (score 0):

I read the paper and the code and it seems the PFP algorithm is not correct at all. I am wondering why nobody hasn't realized it.

It is so obvious if you already know about FP-Growth and just take a couple hours to read this paper and the code.